# Can we detect any two electrons at the exact same time?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons

Can we detect any two electrons at the exact same time?

Lets say all electrons are actually just one electron, and that is why they have exactly the same in spin, charge and so on.

Lets say there is only one electron in the Universe.

Can we detect any two electrons at the exact same time?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is gibberish.

Comment: Is electrical current one electron?

Comment: In the old [One Electron Universe idea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-electron_universe), which probably was more of a joke than a serious proposal, the electron traveled backward and forward in time, and thus could be in many places at once.  I don't know whether anything is wrong with the "one electron" idea, but even if nothing is wrong with it, nothing is right with it either:  It does not explain anything that can't be explained by more conventional theories.

Comment: why would not? Even if it was the same electron, to us it would exist at multiple places simultaneously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, i remembered reading feynman when i saw this question . I know this question doesn't make sense to a lot of people but many great discoveries were actually done that way .This idea was proposed by John Wheeler to Feynman on a telephone call.For more details,visit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-electron_universe.
This idea wasn't supported back then and i don't think that even feynman believed in this very much.But such ideas could sometimes be true .Our proof is quantum mechanics and relativity and also the more recent proposition of dark matter by Fritz Zwicky in Caltech that we still don't understand fully.Considering this question, we say that the electron can travel back and forth in time in this model.

So, actually we can detect two electrons at the same time(if it can go in a loop).Moreover,in feynmann approach to quantum mechanics,we take into account all the paths that the particle can take and the particle takes them all simulatneously.

Once other crazy idea of feynman i would like to mention is that anti particles are particles travelling back in time.(google it if you like).

Comment: So did they prove the one electron universe by detecting two electrons at the same time or how did they do it?   Have anyone tried to detect two electrons at the same time to prove one electron universe?

Comment: We still haven't proved the one electron universe but it's a nice idea. Detecting two electron's at the same time has been done but indirectly in quantum mechanics.The only possible explanation given for the behavior of sub atomic particles can be explained by this phenomenon .Some non local hidden variable theories try to do this too but they are more weirder than quantum mechanics.Personally, i don't know an experiment where a particle has been observed in two places simultaneously.

Comment: @user3688410 you can check out this video too https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9dqtW9MslFk